# How can I use different provider to send SMS from Acumatica ERP?

Tags: c#, acumatica, acumatica-kb

Out-of-box Acumatica has `Twilio` and `Amazon SNS` providers to send SMS. However, we have a business relationship with different provider (`Plivo` for example) and would like to utilize them for SMS service. Is it possible to use different provider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use different provider to send SMS.

In Acumatica, SMS service is used for

1. sending access code during [two-factor authentication](https://help-2019r2.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=e612d54b-72d9-400c-b913-cdfa02220c58)
2. sending [business notifications](https://help-2019r2.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=6d9e5b08-164d-4eb8-82a6-a41136a3b8cf)

Acumatica ERP provides set of interfaces to implement SMS provider for sending SMS message.

**1. PX.SmsProvider.ISmsProvider**

Classes implementing this interface are automatically discovered by Acumatica ERP and are available for selection in the `Provider Type` box on the SMS Provider (`SM203535`) screen. Classes must be part of Library (DLL).

Define class implementing `PX.SmsProvider.ISmsProvider` interface and implement methods of `ISmsProvider` interface.

```cs
public class MySmsProvider : ISmsProvider
{        
    public IEnumerable<PXFieldState> ExportSettings
    {
        // Implement definition of each setting/parameter and add to settings list
        get
        {
            return new List<PXFieldState>();
        }
    }

    public void LoadSettings(IEnumerable<ISmsProviderSetting> settings)
    {
        // Retrieve value of each setting/parameter and assign to corresponding member variable
    }

    public async Task SendMessageAsync(SendMessageRequest request, CancellationToken cancellation)
    {
        // Implement logic to send SMS
    }
}
```

**2. PX.SmsProvider.ISmsProviderFactory**

Class implementing constructor to initialize provider. And public properties to hold Name and Description for this provider – the way you need it to be displayed in Provider Type box on the SMS Provider (SM203535) screen.

Define class implementing `PX.SmsProvider.ISmsProviderFactory` interface and implement methods and properties of `ISmsProviderFactory` interface.

```cs
public class MySmsProviderFactory : ISmsProviderFactory
{
    //Create Provider and initialize with settings
    public ISmsProvider Create(IEnumerable<ISmsProviderSetting> settings)
    {
        var provider = new MySmsProvider();
        provider.LoadSettings(settings);
        return provider;
    }

    public ISmsProvider Create()
    {
        var provider = new MySmsProvider();
        return provider;
    }

    public string Description { get; } = "My Provider";
    public string Name { get; } = typeof(MySmsProvider).FullName;
}
```

**Below example illustrates creating SMS Provider using Plivo Service.**

In C# class library project, add references of `PX.Common.dll`, `PX.Data.dll` and `PX.SmsProvider.Core.dll` from your Acumatica Site’s bin folder.

Definition of `PlivoSmsProvider` class implementing `PX.SmsProvider.ISmsProvider` interface:
We will need `Auth ID`, `Auth Token` and `From Number` parameters to work with Plivo. So, we will set them up in `ExportSettings` method and assign them to member variables in `LoadSettings` method. And we will implement logic to send SMS in `SendMessageAsync`.

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using PX.Data;

namespace PX.SmsProvider.Plivo
{
    public class PlivoSmsProvider : ISmsProvider
    {
        #region DetailIDs const
        private const string AuthID_DetailID = "AUTH_ID";
        private const string AuthToken_DetailID = "AUTH_TOKEN";
        private const string FromPhoneNbr_DetailID = "FROM_PHONE_NBR";
        #endregion

        #region DetailID_Display const
        private const string AuthID_DetailID_Display = "Auth ID";
        private const string AuthToken_DetailID_Display = "Auth Token";
        private const string FromPhoneNbr_DetailID_Display = "From Number";
        #endregion

        private string m_AuthID;
        public string AuthID { get { return m_AuthID; } }

        private string m_AuthToken;
        public string AuthToken { get { return m_AuthToken; } }

        private string m_FromPhoneNbr;
        public string FromPhoneNbr { get { return m_FromPhoneNbr; } }

        public IEnumerable<PXFieldState> ExportSettings
        {
            get
            {
                var settings = new List<PXFieldState>();

                var authID = (PXStringState)PXStringState.CreateInstance(
                    m_AuthID,
                    null,
                    false,
                    AuthID_DetailID,
                    null,
                    1,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null
                );
                authID.DisplayName = AuthID_DetailID_Display;
                settings.Add(authID);
                var authToken = (PXStringState)PXStringState.CreateInstance(
                    m_AuthToken,
                    null,
                    false,
                    AuthToken_DetailID,
                    null,
                    1,
                    "*",
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null
                );
                authToken.DisplayName = AuthToken_DetailID_Display;
                settings.Add(authToken);

                var fromPhoneNbr = (PXStringState)PXStringState.CreateInstance(
                    m_FromPhoneNbr,
                    null,
                    false,
                    FromPhoneNbr_DetailID,
                    null,
                    1,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null
                );
                fromPhoneNbr.DisplayName = FromPhoneNbr_DetailID_Display;
                settings.Add(fromPhoneNbr);

                return settings;
            }
        }

        public void LoadSettings(IEnumerable<ISmsProviderSetting> settings)
        {
            foreach (ISmsProviderSetting detail in settings)
            {
                switch (detail.Name.ToUpper())
                {
                    case AuthID_DetailID: m_AuthID = detail.Value; break;
                    case AuthToken_DetailID: m_AuthToken = detail.Value; break;
                    case FromPhoneNbr_DetailID: m_FromPhoneNbr = detail.Value; break;
                }
            }
        }

        public async Task SendMessageAsync(SendMessageRequest request, CancellationToken cancellation)
        {
            // implement logic to send SMS
        }
    }
}
```

Definition of `PlivoSmsProviderFactory` class implementing `PX.SmsProvider.ISmsProviderFactory` interface.

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace PX.SmsProvider.Plivo
{
    public class PlivoSmsProviderFactory : ISmsProviderFactory
    {
        public ISmsProvider Create(IEnumerable<ISmsProviderSetting> settings)
        {
            var provider = new PlivoSmsProvider();
            provider.LoadSettings(settings);
            return provider;
        }

        public ISmsProvider Create()
        {
            var provider = new PlivoSmsProvider();
            return provider;
        }

        public string Description { get; } = "Plivo SMS Provider";
        public string Name { get; } = typeof(PlivoSmsProvider).FullName;
    }
}
```

Once this library is published via customization, this New provider will be available in SMS Providers (SM203535) screen.

[image: SMS Providers]

[Download Acumatica Source code and Customization deployment package](https://github.com/DhirenChhapgar/Acumatica-SMS-Provider-Plivo)